# Read labels separately from a function that generates a set of buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, elementtree

I have the following development that I am working on with the Tkinter, ElementTree and Pandas modules in Python:

```
    from tkinter import *
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    
    file_xml = ET.parse('example1.xml')
    rootXML = file_xml.getroot()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Graphical Analysis of Signals of a XML")
    root.geometry("1024x820")
    root.pack_propagate(False)
    root.config(bd=15)

    # Functions to open xml file
    def open_file():
       try:
          global temxml, xml_Name
          xml_Name = str(easygui.fileopenbox(title='Select xml file', default='*.xml'))
          if str(os.path.abspath(xml_Name)) != os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), os.path.basename(xml_Name)):
              menssage.set("Opened xml file: ", xml_Name)
              child_4_separate(os.path.basename(str(tempxml)))
          else:
              child_4_separate(os.path.basename(str(xml_Name)))
       except FileNotFoundError:
           print('XML file was not loaded.')
    
    # Function to display buttons and choose the Child_4 to be plotted
    def child_4_separate(xml_Name):
        print("File: ", xml_Name)
        file_xml = ET.parse(xml_Name)
        data_xml = [
            {
                "Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
                "Id": signal.attrib["Id"],
            } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Child_4")
        ]
        # print(data_xml)
    
        for i in data_xml:
           print(i)
           id_tc = i.get('Id')
           dict_tc = str(i.values()).replace('dict_values([\'', '')
           name_tc = dict_tc.replace('\'])', '')
           Button(root, text=f"TC> {name_tc}", command=transfor_data_atri_child_4(xml_Name, id_tc)).pack()

    # Function to transform xml file to DataFrame
    def transfor_data_atri_child_4(rootXML, id_tc):
        print("File: ", rootXML)
        print("id_tc: ", id_tc)
```

What I'm trying to do is that every time I click a button, the `child_4_separate (xml_Name)` function it goes to the `transform_data_atri_child_4 (rootXML, id_tc)` function with a single id number and does not fetch me everything like it does in the last print that I show below, this is to be able to manipulate them separately.

[image: console output]

I share the XML file in this link [example1.xml](https://github.com/MR/blob/master/exam.xml) because of how long it is.

I don't know if I need another for inside or what I need, because when trying another for inside the already existing for in the `child_4_separate (xml_Name)` function it is repeating it many times and it is not what I want, but simply that redirect to the following function with the two parameters that I am indicating, but separately; help me please! Beforehand, thank you very much!

Comment: ```command=lambda x=xml_Name,y=id_tc: transfor_data_atri_child_4(x,y)```, might help

Comment: Thank you very much @Sujay, I applied what you tell me and it worked.

Comment: Most Welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for possible searches or related problems later, I share the solution:

Take the value `command = lambda x = xml_Name, y = id_tc: transform_data_atri_child_4 (x, y)` in the button attributes and it worked, my function is like this:

```
    # Function to display buttons and choose the Child_4 to be plotted
    def child_4_separate(xml_Name):
        # print("File: ", xml_Name)
        file_xml = ET.parse(xml_Name)
        data_xml = [
            {
               "Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
               "Id": signal.attrib["Id"],
            } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Child_4")
        ]
        # print(data_xml)

       for i in data_xml:
          id_tc = i.get('Id')
          dict_tc = str(i.values()).replace('dict_values([\'', '')
          name_tc = dict_tc.replace('\'])', '')
          Button(root, text=f"TC> {name_tc}", command=lambda x=xml_Name, y=id_tc: transfor_data_atri_child_4(x, y)).pack()
```

I appreciate the solution to @Sujay. Happy codification everyone!!